# How does spark move computation to data in HBase?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, hbase

I do have successfully accessed data from `Hbase` to `Spark` before. However I found a problem that the computation did not move to data within Spark. For example, I have 10 regions with data in 5 physical nodes and I wanna access its' data with `Spark-2.4.0`, it's weird that only 3 nodes of the cluster launch tasks. What's wrong with my cluster?

There is some of conditions I have configured:

1. The cluster have totally 5 physical nodes running with `Hadoop`, `HBase`, `Zookeeper` and `Spark`.
2. I am sure that the data was stored evenly in 10 regions of 5 nodes. In other words, If i wanna access data 1 to 10, the regionServer1 to regionServer10 will be called.
   [image]
3. I am using "newAPIHadoopRDD" to access data from `HBase`, the API does not contain partition configuration at all, so the default threads' count that `Executors` could launch is the count of `HRegions`.
   [image]

The phenomemon is that only 3 nodes of cluster lauched totally 10 tasks. I expected that all of 5 nodes launch tasks and, each node ought to launch 2 tasks. I have realized that `Hbase` is based on `HDFS`, but I have no idea about that API "newAPIHadoopRDD", so I also wanna find out how it works.

Comment: Is Spark on a separate CLUSTER?

Comment: @thebluephantom Oh yeas, actually the cluster runs on virtual environment but it doesn't matter.